# How to remove relationship between many to many table with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables: Recipe table and Account table. The Recipe table stores a number of recipes. The account table stores a number of user account. A user can be associated with 0 or more recipe. When a user likes a recipe, this user is associated to the recipe. To record this association, I created a table called LikedRecipe table.

These are the columns of each table:

- Recipe: id, name. Id is the primary key.
- Account: email, password. Email is the primary key.
- LikedRecipe: id, name, email. id is the primary key.

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Recipe")
  public class Recipe {

  private Set<Account> account;

  private Long id;


  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "LikedRecipe", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipeId"),     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "email"))
  public Set<Account> getAccount() {
  return account;
  }

  public void setAccount(Set<Account> account) {
  this.account = account;
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Long getId() {
  return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
  }
  }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Account")
  public class Account implements Serializable {

  private Set<Recipe> likedRecipes = new HashSet<Recipe>();

  private String email;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
  @JoinTable(name = "LikedRecipe", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "email"),  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipeId"))
  public Set<Recipe> getLikedRecipes() {
  return likedRecipes;
  }


  public void setLikedRecipes(Set<Recipe> likedRecipes) {
  this.likedRecipes = likedRecipes;
  }

  @Column(name = "email")
  @Id
  public String getEmail() {
  return email;
  }


  public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
  }
  }
  ```

I wrote a method to remove the association between an account and a recipe:

```
public void unlikeARecipe(String email, Long recipeId){
Query query = entityManager
    .createQuery("delete from LikedRecipe where recipeId = :recipeId and email  = :email");
query.setParameter("recipeId", recipeId);
query.setParameter("email", email);
query.executeUpdate();
}
```

This method did not delete records from LikedRecipe table, until I added this line of code at the end of the method:

`entityManager.clear();`

According to JPA API documentation the clear method clears the persistence context, causing all managed entities to become detached.

My question is what does detach means ? And, how does detaching objects made the above method deletes records from LikedRecipe table? Am I using the clear method in the right manner ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detached entity is an entity not currently managed by a persistence context  but whose id is present in database.

I think you don't get the LikedRecipe entity deleted because you still have it referenced from other persistent entities (Account and Recipe). Indeed it works when you clear the persistence context, detaching all entities that are "keeping alive" the LikedRecipe you wanted to delete.

If you want to keep the many-to-many relationships, you have to clear them as well (i.e. removing the object from Account's and Recipe's collections) when you're about to deleting the LikedRecipe entity.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn´t be better to make design something like:

  - Recipe(id,name)
  - User(email, ...)
  - LikedRecipe(userEmail, recipeId)?

And don´t make relationship in recipe for users, it´s (in my humble opinion) useless relationship.
To this case it´s enough to make OneToMany relationship from User (/Account) to Recipe and none relation in Recipe for Users.

Comment: The intention in creating a relationship from recipe to user is to keep track the number of users who liked a recipe. This capability is critical whenever I have to display a list of recipes with the number of users who likes each recipe.

Comment: There is another way to reach this goal. You can also use JPQL (SQL variant for JPA) and create method to get count of users for given recipe - simple count function on LikedRecipe table :)