# JPA " org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException" while deleting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, entity

Am having a entity object as below and when I try to delete the Parent entity object am getting the "org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException" but am not sure what is the reason for this exception.

```
Class Parent implements Serializable
{
@ID
@column(name="ParentKey")
String parentKey;

@manytomany
@jointabel(name="Association_Parent_Child",joinColumns{ @joinColumn,@inversejoinColumn})
List<Child> Childs;

}

Below is the Child Entity

Class Child implements Serializabe
{
 @ID
 @column(name="childKey")
 String childKey;

 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Childs", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
 List<Parent> parents;

@onetomany
List<someOtherClassX> x;

@onetomany
List<SomeotherClassY> y;
}
```

In my DAO Implementation Layer . I have a delete Method

```
Parent DeletParent = new Parent ();
DeletParent .setParentKey("ID");
```

When I call entitymanager.remove("DeletParent ");

```
  <openjpa-2.0.0-r422266:935683 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: 
This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types 
were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: "
com.ibm.sales.cgsp.busobj.Parent
com.ibm.sales.cgsp.busobj.Child".
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:116)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:304)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:228)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:202)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:213)
at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:42)
at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:519)
at $Proxy15.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:233)
at $Proxy20.contains(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.impl.ClientStrategicGoalDAOImpl.deleteClientStrategyByGoal(ClientStrategicGoalDAOImpl.java:76)
at com.ibm.sales.cgsp.dao.test.ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.testDeleteClientStrategicGoal(ClientStrategicGoalDAOTest.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any suggestions , As per the exception should we populate the child object . Why do we have to populate the child object here.?

Comment: Looks like there are childrens to parent and you can not delete when you have a reference. Do you want to delete child, when parent is deleted? or you want to make parent reference null?

Comment: @Gayathri Thanks for the response. I don want to delete the child while deleting parent. What am thinking is as its a manytomany relationship child may be mapped to some other record, When you delete the parent it should delete from the association table parent_child and then from parent table .  Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Well, in that case, first you need to get all children, then associate with other parent and delete parent.

Comment: IMO: when the error refers to enhancement issues it has absolutely nothing to do with mapping problems but rather with how the entities are enriched (at runtime using for example Javassist proxies or before compilation through a build script). But I have no experience using OpenJPA so I can't give a true answer here.

Comment: @Gayathri but any specific reason why do we need to populate the child . As it has to delete the parent references from association table and then from parent table. Am not able to get the relation as to why we need to populate the child. it should be like "delete from association where parentKey = "ID" " and "delete from parent where parentkey="ID" . Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @Gimby Ya even am trying to implement JPA for the first time and am kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the parent:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
```

Comment: @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.DETACH). I added this in parent. No exceptions now .  But I can only see select queries in my console. No delete queries at all and No record is getting deleted

Comment: Check out the link below: looks like its same as what you are facing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818210/how-to-remove-relationship-between-many-to-many-table-with-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: I followed that link . It's quite similar to mine .. But using clear() not helping as same issues its generating only select Queries when we call remove()

Comment: I strongly feel it should be with cascade type. give {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}

Comment: I used it as below " @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH}) "  . Still the same . also used CascadeType.All. It's still deleting nothing only generating select queries .

Comment: Thanks for the help in solving the exception with cascadetype.detatch attribute . Also I was able to solve the above not deleting issues by doing two things . First to get the object from the context by calling entitymanager.find() and then managing the object as a transaction entity by providing transaction annotation. It works now thanks